# sklearn MultinomialNB only predicts class priors

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am currently try to roll my own naive bayes classifier for categorical features to make sure I understood them. Now I wanted to compare them with sklearns `MultinomialNB`. But for some reason, I can't get the skearn version to run correctly.
Easiest thing to compare I thought was the kaggle Titanic dataset. So it did this (which is fairly simple, right?):

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

train = pd.read_csv('data/in/train.csv')

X = np.asarray(train[['Pclass']])
y = np.asarray(train['Survived'])

clf = MultinomialNB()
clf.fit(X, y)
clf.predict_proba(X)
```

But what it actually predicts (or not, in this case...) is that everyone on the Titanic dies. Or in other words when the class labels to predict are `[0, 1]`, it predicts 0. The weirdest thing is, that it apparently just gives out the probabilities of the **class prior** P(y) (which I checked with my homebrewn algorithm ;)) for every prediction. So it apparently doesn't multiply it with the likelihood P(X|y).

Has anyone ever encountered this? Am I making some apparent mistake here?

**Edit:**

I think I got it now. If I transform the input dataset into a contingency table, and one-hot encode the input feature, it gives the same predicted probabilities. I used a smoothing of `alpha=0` for comparison with my own algorithm:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

train = pd.read_csv('data/in/train.csv')

X_test = np.asarray(pd.get_dummies(train['Pclass']))

X = np.array(pd.crosstab(train[y_column], train['Pclass']))
y = np.array([0,1])

clf = MultinomialNB(alpha=0.0000000001, class_prior=np.array(class_prior))
clf.fit(X, y)
clf.predict_proba(X_test)
```

still, one thing I wonder about is, why I had to manually specify the class prior now. If I wouldn't have done that, sklearn now used an uninformed prior, `[0.5, 0.5]`...

Comment: You are training on just one feature. Maybe that feature is highly correlated with the label so P(X|y) is close to 1. Can you try with another feature?

Comment: Hey Selçuk, I tried it with other features as well, but it still only gives me the class prior. I also tried it with two features. The interesting thing happening then is, that it doesn't give me the class prior, _except_ when all features are 0.
However, I still don't trust the result for two features. My algorithm gives me completely different results (which can of course be the fault of my algorithm ;). But since the 1 feature case doesn't work in sklearn...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Multinomial Naive Bayes model is working exactly as it is supposed to work given a single feature. If you take a look at the [formula for P(X|y)](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/naive_bayes.html#multinomial-naive-bayes), it is equal to 1 when the number of features n=1. Here is why.

The Naive Bayes models differ from each other by assumptions they make about the conditional distribution P(X | y). The Multinomial Naive Bayes assumes this is a multinomial distribution. The multinomial distribution  models the probability of counts for rolling a (possibly biased) k-sided die n times.

Suppose, for example, that you are given a party of dice produced by two companies: FairDice and Crooks&Co. FairDice is known to produce to fair dice, and Crooks&Co produces loaded dice that overwhelmingly fall with 6 on top. You are asked to learn to predict a die's producer from throwing it several times and looking at the results. You throw each die several times and record the results in a dataset with 6 features. Each feature represents how many times the corresponding value occured when throwing a die.

```
count_1 count_2 count_3 count_4 count_5 count_6 fair_dice
5       6       4       7       6       5       1
3       2       1       2       1       13      0
```

Now this is an appropriate dataset for training a Multinomial Naive Bayes classifier.

Training a Multinomial Naive Bayes classifier on a single feature is equivalent to trying to classify one-sided dice with the same number on top.

[image: A one-sided die. They are real!]
A one-sided die. They exist!

E.g. if your feature has values [3,2,1], it means that you threw the first die three times and got 1 every time, threw the second die twice and got 1 both times, threw the third dice once and got 1. This gives you no information on the dice producer, so the best you can predict is the class prior, which is exactly what the algorithm does.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So apparently the problem was that the input was not in the correct format. I updated my original post with a working solution. I think I got confused by sklearn's documentation, which states, that the input must be of shape `[n_samples, n_features]`, whereas it apparently must be `[n_classes, n_features]`. The only confusing thing now is, why sklearn doesn't compute the class prior automatically in the new algorithm.
Also, thanks for letting me know of one-sided dice. They might come handy one day, you'll never know ;)